cannot open source file "sal.h" while configuring mpi with VS CODE
I'm currently setting up Visual Studio Code (VS Code) for MPI development and have ensured that all required Environment Variables are properly configured. However, I've encountered a significant issue:
Problem: Unable to import <mpi.h> in my code file.
Root Cause: Unable to import <sal.h> in my mpi.h file.
Cause: The compiler reports it cannot open the source file "sal.h".
Here's my code snippet:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
       
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    
    printf("Hello from process %d\n", rank);
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

Additionally, this is the content of my task.json file:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "${MSMPI_INC}",
                "-L",
                "${MSMPI_LIB64}",
                "-lmsmpi",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}

Furthermore, this is my configurecpp.json file:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${MSMPI_INC}",
                "${MSMPI_LIB32}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


VSCode is not configured by setting environment variables. Normally you edit the tasks.json file (but this does depend on what method you are using to build your C++ code).

VSCode is complex to configure correctly, if you want to use it, you must read the documentation.

These are intellisense errors, how have you configured intellisense? Please don't post images of code and error messages, post the text instead

yes i have configured intellisense with env variables MSMPI_INC. @AlanBirtles, and i have also configured vs code with env variables

Which environment variables have you set? Are you sure the vscode documentation states that it looks at those environment variables?

hmm. unable to get you sorry!! .is it problem with my vscode or gcc, mingw, or mpi sdk, please look at question again i have added configuration files. What should be my next step??

Note that the VSCode documentation specifically tells you to use MSYS2 to install the compiler (and not use any old mingw version). Also, use g++ to compile C++, gcc is for C.

You aren't using the right syntax for using environment variables
